# How do I remove a specific part of a URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently I have the following piece of code on my .htaccess to remove a string that follows a tilde in my URL:

```
# Tilde removal from URL (e.g. example.com/~tildestuff/about to example.com/about)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /~\w+/(\S+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /~\w+
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

This works for the most part however if I enter the this URL:

http://www.example.com/~example/public/

It does not redirect, but this does work:

http://www.example.com/~example/about-us

And gets redirected to:

http://www.example.com/about-us

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: those rules work for me

Answer (score 0):

It should have worked with your rule already. Try adding a slash at the end of the first rule :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /~\w+/(\S+/?) [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /~\w+
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]
```